# quesion about the axis of tf.stack()

Tags: tensorflow

I read the doc of `tf.stack()` on [tensorflow stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) . There is an example on the page:

```
>>> x = tf.constant([1, 4])
>>> y = tf.constant([2, 5])
>>> z = tf.constant([3, 6])
>>> sess=tf.Session()
>>> sess.run(tf.stack([x, y, z]))
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]], dtype=int32)
>>> sess.run(tf.stack([x, y, z], axis=1))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)
```

what I don't understand is the second example where `axis=1`.

From the result it seems it converts the three inputs rows to columns first

and then put them toghter along the `axis=1`, but

I think the result should be

```
array([[1,4, 2, 5, 3, 6 ]] dtype=int32 )
```

can anyone help explain this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tf.stack` always adds a new dimension, and always concatenates the given tensor along that new dimension. In your case, you have three tensors with shape `[2]`. Setting `axis=0` is the same as adding a new first dimension, so each tensor would now have shape `[1, 2]`, and concatenating across that dimension, so the final shape would be `[3, 2]`. That is, each tensor would be a "row" of the final tensor. With `axis=1` the shapes of each individual tensor would be extended to `[2, 1]`, and the result would have shape `[2, 3]`. So each given tensor would be a "column" of the resulting tensor.

In other words, `tf.stack` is functionally equivalent to this:

```
def tf.stack(tensors, axis=0):
    return tf.concatenate([tf.expand_dims(t, axis=axis) for t in tensors], axis=axis)
```

But the result that you expect would be obtained with something like this:

```
tf.concatenate([tf.expand_dims(t, axis=0) for t in tensors], axis=1)
```

Note that the added dimension and the concatenation dimension are different in this case.

Comment: Can we generalize this for any axis and somehow use a bunch of tf.concatenate() to perform the functionality of tf.stack()?

Comment: @skadaver What exactly is the functionality that you want to perform? The definition that I put as equivalent of `tf.stack` does pretty much that, I think.